# Using underscore or lodash or vanilla js, how to figure out which element of an array occurs most frequently?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

If I have an array that contains objects, how would I figure out which object occurs most frequently in that array?

Lets say the array is an array containing products, each product is an object with a unique id (unique per product not per element in the array):

```
const products = [
  {
    "itemId": "573412ab18c933d0085ca8b2",
    "price": 20,
    "cartQuantity": 1,
    "itemName": "Tea"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "573c82bd5c5ade1100532ec0",
    "price": 100,
    "cartQuantity": 1,
    "itemName": "Carpet"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "5734126218c933d0085ca8b0",
    "_id": "57608d4187faf12708605360",
    "price": 15,
    "cartQuantity": 1,
    "itemName": "Black Coffee"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "573412dd18c933d0085ca8b3",
    "_id": "57608d3d87faf12708605362",
    "price": 50,
    "cartQuantity": 1,
    "itemName": "Nyquil"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "573412ab18c933d0085ca8b2",
    "price": 20,
    "cartQuantity": 1,
    "itemName": "Tea"
  }
];
```

In the above snippet, you can see "Tea" occurs most frequently. I currently lack the algorithmic knowledge necessary to figure out how to pull the "Tea" object from that array as the most frequently occurring element. Also, if someone can help me here, it would be important to keep in mind an exception case where two elements in the array occur an equal amount of times and they "tie" for being the most frequent.

If this is an easy problem for someone to solve, please go easy on me and explain with as much detail as your patience permits how you solve this problem as I'm still learning. Feel free to answer with underscore or lodash functions!

Comment: What should be the result in the case of a *tie*?

Comment: @Phil that is a good question. I assumed an array of items in my solution below, but it's a good thing to clarify.

Comment: @jmancherje my solution provides an array of object that contains id of the item and ocurrences for that item and it's sorted by the number of ocurrences, with this array you can check easily if more than one item have the same number of ocurrences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format your output like :

```
[
  {
    "itemId": "573412ab18c933d0085ca8b2",
    "ocurrences": 2
  },
  {
    "itemId": "573c82bd5c5ade1100532ec0",
    "ocurrences": 1
  },
  ...
  ]
```

What is a sorted array where the first element is the most repeated in the array. As is sorted you can easily check if the second or the next elements have the same number of ocurrences .

To achieve this you need something like this :

```js
let getOcurrences = array =>{
  let ocurrences = {};
  array.forEach(item=>{
    if (!ocurrences[item.itemId])
      ocurrences[item.itemId] = 1;
    else 
      ocurrences[item.itemId] += 1;
  });
  return Object.keys(ocurrences)
    .map(itemId => ({
      itemId : itemId,
      ocurrences : ocurrences[itemId]
    }))
    .sort((a, b)=> b.ocurrences - a.ocurrences);
};

const products = [
  {
    "itemId": "573412ab18c933d0085ca8b2",
    "price": 20,
    "cartQuantity": 1,
    "itemName": "Tea"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "573c82bd5c5ade1100532ec0",
    "price": 100,
    "cartQuantity": 1,
    "itemName": "Carpet"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "5734126218c933d0085ca8b0",
    "_id": "57608d4187faf12708605360",
    "price": 15,
    "cartQuantity": 1,
    "itemName": "Black Coffee"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "573412dd18c933d0085ca8b3",
    "_id": "57608d3d87faf12708605362",
    "price": 50,
    "cartQuantity": 1,
    "itemName": "Nyquil"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "573412ab18c933d0085ca8b2",
    "price": 20,
    "cartQuantity": 1,
    "itemName": "Tea"
  }
];
console.log(getOcurrences(products));
```

Comment: What is this bit of code doing? 
 return Object.keys(ocurrences)
    .map(itemId => ({
      itemId : itemId,
      ocurrences : ocurrences[itemId]
    }))
    .sort((a, b)=> b.ocurrences - a.ocurrences);

I am not sure what Object.keys() is accomplishing here.

Comment: @Mjuice ocurrences is an object like this {"52jkh298728..." : "2", ...} so Object.keys(ocurrences) obtains the keys (itemsID) . for each key I generate with "map" I generate a list with objects like this   {"itemId": "573412ab18c933d0085ca8b2","ocurrences": 2 } and sort that list.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to iterate through the array and adding each itemId of the current product to an object as a key as you go (with a value containing the count as 1, and the index in the array).

If the element is already in the object increment the count value by 1. In the end you just find the max count value in the object.

A solution:

```
function mostOccuringProduct(productList) {
  const frequencies = {};

  // iterating through each product counting the occurrence of each itemId
  productList.forEach((product, i) => {
    if (product.itemId in frequencies) {
      frequencies[product.itemId].count++;
    } else {
      frequencies[product.itemId] = { count: 1, index: i };
    }
  })

  // find max number of occurences of any 1 item
  const maxOccurences = _.max(frequencies, item => item.count);
  // get array of items that tie for this maxOccurences #
  const itemsMatchingMaxOccurences = _.filter(frequencies, item => item.count === maxOccurences.count);
  // create array of just the indicies of the items that tie for the maxNumber of occurences
  const indicesOfMaxOccuringItems = _.map(itemsMatchingMaxOccurences, frequency => frequency.index);

  // initialize an array to hold all items that tie for max occurencies
  const products = [];
  // push items to this array
  indicesOfMaxOccuringItems.forEach(index => products.push(productList[index]));


  // return an array of all products that occur most frequently.
  // or just return the product that occurs most IF there is only one.
  return products.length > 1 ? products : products[0];
}
```

This solution will return an array of products that tie for the most occurrences in the list. If there's only one item it will return 1 item.

Comment: I'm working on optimizing this a little and i'll edit the solution in a few minutes

Comment: I missed the mention of the edge case where multiple elements tie. I'll add that to this solution as well.

Comment: note that [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is a part of ES6; underscore is unnecessary in this example

Comment: @Hamms Thanks for letting me know. I removed it in my new edit.

Answer (score 0):

I propose using a hashmap to count occurences while iterating over the products & keeping track of the most frequent product:

```js
function getMostFrequent(array, identityFn) {
  var counts = {}, max = 0, result;
  
  array.forEach(element => {
    var id = (identityFn && identityFn(element)) || element,
        count = counts[id] = (counts[id] || 0) + 1;
    if (count > max) {
      max = count;
      result = element;
    }
  });
  return result;
}

const products = [{"itemId": 1}, {"itemId": 2}, {"itemId": 2}, {"itemId": 3}];

var mostFrequent = getMostFrequent(products, p => p["itemId"]);

console.log(mostFrequent);
```

If you want *all* products tied for the most frequent instead of just the first, declare result as `Array` and push elements on `count == max`.

**Explanation of `getMostFrequent()`:**

We iterate over all elements in the given `array` and for each element we...

- get its `id` via supplied `identityFn` callback function
- initialize or increase the counter for this `id` by `counts[id] = (counts[id] || 0) + 1;`
- and finally compare to the most frequent element so far and update if this one occurs more often.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my **O(n)** solution. We create a hash table and keep the counts within the hash table in a separate property called indices which is an array. When an item gets it's first occurrence it's index value (in the products array) gets inserted at indices array index position 1. When another item gets it's first occurrence it overwrites index position 1. So when an item gets it's second occurrence it get's inserted at indices[2] and so on. At the end indices.pop() will give us the most frequent product's item's index and we are not morphing the products array.

```js
var products = [
  {
    "itemId": "573412ab18c933d0085ca8b2",
    "price": 20,
    "cartQuantity": 1,
    "itemName": "Tea"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "573c82bd5c5ade1100532ec0",
    "price": 100,
    "cartQuantity": 1,
    "itemName": "Carpet"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "5734126218c933d0085ca8b0",
    "_id": "57608d4187faf12708605360",
    "price": 15,
    "cartQuantity": 1,
    "itemName": "Black Coffee"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "573412dd18c933d0085ca8b3",
    "_id": "57608d3d87faf12708605362",
    "price": 50,
    "cartQuantity": 1,
    "itemName": "Nyquil"
  },
  {
    "itemId": "573412ab18c933d0085ca8b2",
    "price": 20,
    "cartQuantity": 1,
    "itemName": "Tea"
  }
],
lut = products.reduce((p,c,i) => { ++p[c.itemId] || (p[c.itemId] = 1);
                                   p.indices[p[c.itemId]] = i;
                                   return p;
                                 },{indices:[]});
console.log(lut);
console.log(products[lut.indices[lut.indices.length-1]]);
```